# Bind to last N elements of a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I use wpf toolkit charts to display some data stored in a `ObservableCollection`. When there are more than N items stored in that collection only the last N items should be displayed (I cannot delete any items).

**XAML**

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValueBinding="{Binding DoubleValue,Converter={StaticResource DoubleValueConverter}}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DataSourceConverter}}"/>
```

**DataSourceConverter**

```
public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ICollection<object> items = value as ICollection<object>;

        int N = 300;

        if (items != null)
        {
            return items.Skip(Math.Max(0, items.Count - N)).Take(N);
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }  
    }
```

ItemSource is bound to a `ObservableCollection`containing both "DoubleValue" and "Count". It seems like `DataSourceConverter` is called only once and not when my `ObservableCollection` is updated.

Comment: Just make another collection and copy the relevant items to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about the converter, make a new property in your viewmodel class, which returns the last 300 items (just like you have declared it now in your converter), and bind to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ICollectionView and set a Filter on it.

From your ObservableCollection, create a new CollectionView:

```
CollectionView topNItems = (CollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myObservableCollection);
```

Next, create the filter on your CollectionView:

```
topNItems.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyTopNItems);
```

And finally the filter event:

```
private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    int n = 300;
    int listCount = myObservableCollection.Count;
    int indexOfItem = myObservableCollection.IndexOf(e.Item);
    e.Accepted = (listCount - indexOfItem) < n;
}
```

Now, bind your chart to the new topNItems instead of to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: I agree! I just would use this code: `CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
            collectionViewSource.Source = viewModel.YourObservableCollection;
            collectionViewSource.Filter += /*... */` and then I would bind `collectionViewSource.View` property.